# What is the minimum SDK version support for Material Design 3 (M3) in Compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3, android-min-sdk

What is the minimum SDK version support for Material Design 3 (M3) in Compose?

Comment: [Compose Material 3](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-material3). I think minimum is Android 5, but in the link I mentioned there's no Data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acoording to [this official guide](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/setup#create-new), in general you require at least API 21 in Jetpack Compose:

> In the Minimum API level dropdown menu, select API level 21 or higher.

For Material3, there is no extra API version that you need, so you can use Material3 with API level 21. 
You can create a Jetpack Compose Activity in the Android Studio project setup wizard. Just select the option "Empty Compose Activity (Material3)". Then, Android Studio will automatically set up the project for you, and you can verify that it uses API 21.

[image: Android Studio Screenshot]

Also have a look at [this official sample project](https://github.com/android/compose-samples/tree/main/Reply) for Material3 that also uses API 21.